# Laravel Relation based on value within an JSON object

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models in which I need to relate to, a `Users` model and a `Prices` model. In my `Prices` model there is a `JSON object` which holds an `ID` of a user and I was wondering if I could relate to my `Prices` table using the `ID` which is in the `Prices` model?

I know you could use an `getAttribute` and then return the user like that, but I was wondering if there is a `$this->hasOne()` method you could use?

e.g.

**JSON**

`{user_id: 1, other_values:"in the object"}`

**Prices Model**

```
class Prices extends Model { 

    /* Prices has the column 'object' which has the JSON object above */

    protected $casts = ['object' => 'array'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne("App\User", $this->object->user_id, "id"); /* ! Example ! */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I created a package with JSON relationships: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

Since the foreign key is in the `Prices` model, you should use a `BelongsTo` relationship:

```php
class Prices extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = ['object' => 'array'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'object->user_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model  {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function prices() {
       return $this->hasMany(Prices::class, 'object->user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your package are awesome!!
But i have a problems with this
I have a data json like `[{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}]`
How can I make relations with this?

Comment: @VươngNguyễnMinh Take a look at https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations#array-of-objects.

Comment: I struggled whole day to use such nice package. But I am getting the following error: require php ^7.2.5 || ^8.0 -> your php version (7.2; overridden via config.platform, actual: 7.2.5) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: How can I achieve with array like this: [1, 3, 5]

Comment: @ShubhamGupta
class Video extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;
    protected $casts = [
        'package_id'=>'json',
    ];
    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToJson(Package::class,'package_id');
    }
}
class Package extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function videos(){
      return $this->hasManyJson(Video::class,'package_id');
    }
}
Where my video table has multiple package ids in "package_id" column like [1,2,3]